# React native build failed for android RN 0.57.1

Tags: stripe-payments, react-native

I have read the installation guide and setup everything. Payment is working fine with iOS but android is still failed. I have used everything to fix the issue but still facing the same issue.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 19
      compileSdkVersion = 28
      targetSdkVersion = 27
      supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
      googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
}
```

package.json

```
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.1",
"tipsi-stripe": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true" />
```

But the android build failed everytime and i tried everything to resolve this nothing worked.

Here is my issue:

```
> Task :tipsi-stripe:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.app.customer:style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents (aka com.app.customer:style/Theme.MaterialComponents) not found.
  error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton (aka com.app:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton) not found.
  error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button (aka com.mybeautysquad.customer:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button) not found.
  error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense (aka com.app:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense) not found.
  /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6b75366950aa0bad3a0940bb5e9e84dd/res/values/values.xml:87:5-65: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/boxBackgroundColor (aka com.app.customer:attr/boxBackgroundColor)' not found.

  error: failed linking references.
```

Please let me know if anyone can help me into this. It's very important to resolve this issue because iOS app is working fine the only android still live with old version.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

> implementation 'com.android.support:design:**27.1.0**'

to

> implementation 'com.android.support:design:**28.0.0**'

also

> targetSdkVersion = **27**

change it to

> targetSdkVersion = **28**

do a clean build and try again.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the response still same issue.